# New user with 1,493 reputations and more than 20 badges. Possible or a bug?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, reputation, badges

While I am reviewing some first posts and answers of new users in StackOverFlow, I came across with this strange answer. It is posted by a supposed to be a "new user" but with 1493 reputations with more than 20 badges. Is this possible or it is a bug?

[image]

**UPDATE:**

I encountered this yesterday(on Philippine Standard Time), I am a bit busy at work yesterday so I couldn't post it. Here is the full screen shot.

[image]

Comment: And he's been a [`member for 3 years, 10 months`](http://stackoverflow.com/users/94374/patrick).

Comment: I suspect that the user merged accounts after having posted the answer. Not 100% on this though. It may also have been a review audit although without seeing the question, I can't say.

Comment: @Ren, if it was like that, then there should be two S.O. account listed [here](http://stackexchange.com/users/33658/patrick?tab=accounts) , but as it is showing only one, i dont think he has merge his account. A moderator can answer this better i think

Comment: Sometimes I think I encounter Late Answers appearing in the First Post review queue.  Is it possible Patrick has never answered any questions before today?  That would qualify it as a "First answer" as the screenshot dictates.

Comment: @Lucifer - we would never show multiple users in the list there (that doesn't exist at any point in time).  That being said, this user has never been merged.

Comment: @NickCraver , agree but sometimes that list shows it, i have seen it my self in past

Comment: @Lucifer - that's not possible...there's a unique constraints on account to site relations at 2 separate levels, in code and in the DB

Comment: @NickCraver, few months back somebody has posted a question regarding this matter. The list was showing two s.o. accounts there because there was some merging problem created.

Comment: Most likely review audit; guess you clicked "Skip"? In such case, we can never know for sure. :/

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd No I didn't skipped, I pressed the "No Action Needed".

Comment: I cannot locate this post *at all*. Google certainly cannot find anything with those phrases on Stack Overflow. Was it deleted?

Comment: I think it is deleted by the user. As I remember it has a lot of down votes I think.

Comment: Strange, your screenshot is from 3/13 and says "2 hours ago", however the [actual answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14916021/302677) (10K only) was posted on 2/16 and deleted 2/17. Furthermore, the stats on the side are wrong. "other answers: 0" when a 2nd one was posted 12 minutes after the 1st one, "asked: 24 days ago" and "active: 24 days ago" by the question stats, but "answered: today" by the answer stats. It looks like it was a review audit

Comment: @Rachel I encountered this one yesterday but I am too busy at that time that I couldn't post it.

Comment: @Rachel, agree, that answer was deleted by Will♦ Feb 17 at 5:21

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's nothing wrong here, you can see the user by clicking their name and navigating to [the badges tab in their profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/94374/patrick?tab=badges).  Most badges (ones awarded for a specific reason, not for doing `n` things) will show you when and what they were awarded for if you click them.

Additionally, this was an audit, so yes the user can not strictly fit the criteria in those cases (we wouldn't have much of an audit pool in most sites if that was the case).  The point of audits is to see if you're paying attention, you were.

Comment: but he made his first post 2 hours before the snapshot

Comment: If this was his first answer, how did he get [Tenacious] last August? Also, he has 88 answers, according to the profile.

Comment: That's not the reported issue... unless of course the screenshot is faked or taken long time ago which we can't prove. Can't you just see if this was an audit??

Comment: @SamIam - the bug reported is "can this user have this rep and this many badges", yes they sure can.  Should his post be in the first answers queue is an **entirely** different issue.

Comment: @NickCraver That's a terrible reading of the intent of the bug report. Almost everyone else read it as: "Can a user with X years on the site and Y badges be considered a 'new user'?"

Comment: I updated my post with much more information in it. Thanks.

Comment: @LoremIpsum - again there's nothing wrong, I added additional explanation to the answer if you're curious.  We don't discuss audits in detail for good reason.

Comment: @Geobits - it wasn't his *real* first answer - it was an audit in the queue.

Comment: That would have been a simple answer: "It was an audit"

Comment: Oh, so that clears the confusion. Thanks.

Comment: I think you guys need to fix your post-finding logic for the First Posts audits to only pull actual first posts. And fix the "Question" stats below it, like I pointed out [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171900/new-user-with-1-493-reputations-and-more-than-20-badges-possible-or-a-bug#comment509469_171900) :)

Comment: @Rachel - as I stated above we can't do that.  It would either show an old post which would look immediately off, or we'd have a *very* small pool of posts to actually create an audit with, non-existent on smaller sites.

Comment: Wasn't there a suggestion to fake the review time and user info? That would take care of this issue :)

Comment: @Ren - then we'd attribute content to the wrong person, which we just don't do...and whomever copies all the creative commons data is not allowed to do either.

Comment: @NickCraver point taken.

Comment: @NickCraver Can't you just fake their Rep and badges?

Comment: @Rachel - sure I suppose, but there hasn't been a need until now.  I have very little to do with review queues so can't speak to all specifics, but it's something we've discussed for the suggested edit audits.

Comment: @NickCraver Thanks for the update. There are a lot of disassociated posts on a lot of sites (either by request or from user deletions). Can't you pick one of those and "attach" it to a random made up user for purposes of the audit?